# Hive GROUP BY optimization based on cardinality

Tags: group-by, hive

Logically cardinality of columns should matter while doing `GROUP BY` operation. When we write Hive queries involving `GROUP BY`, since we are familiar with the data being queried, we have an idea about cardinality of individual columns involved in the `GROUP BY`. But Hive has no idea about this. So let's say the Hive query in question is:-

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,COUNT(*) FROM MyTable GROUP BY Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
```

I know the degree of cardinality of all the 5 columns here. But Hive doesn't know that, so Hive will probably perform the worst.

So let's say the cardinality information that I have about these columns is like this, from lowest to highest and also giving example of values contained:-

- Col5 = it contains country name
- Col4 = it contains state name
- Col3 = it contains city name
- Col2 = it contains postal code
- Col1 = it contains email address

Now Hive will treat all these the same , won't it be beneficial if Hive knew about underlying cardinality information so it could exploit this in calculating unique groups? In that case if I explicitly arrange the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause in the order of cardinality, will it be efficient as shown in the following example ?

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,COUNT(*) FROM MyTable GROUP BY Col5,Col4,Col3,Col2,Col1
```

Or hive will ignore this order and treat all the columns equally regardless of the order?

Comment: also assume that none of these are partitioned columns

Comment: i think this is mostly depend on the requirement and on developer/user's responsibility. Its impossible for any tool to know your data and its granularity. Some tool can identify depending on the name like month,day,year, hour,min,sec or country,state,province etc. but its nearly impossible to tell hive to keep them in mind while fetching data. Now, you can partition based on col5.col4 etc. which will tell hive to go to correct partition.  so you can partition based on data and hope users follow those partitions.

Comment: My question is precisely that -- I don't expect Hive to know that , but the question is how to technically provide that hint to hive , if I just re-arrange columns in GROUP BY clause based on cardinality , will it help performance or Hive will act the same regardless of that order. Now , as I already said , these columns are not partitioned -- that changes the whole scenario , so the question is specifically about non partitioned columns only.

Comment: if its not partitioned its useless. hive will read all data from whole table anyways so not 100% sure how can you provide hint. You can also try indexing but again it can be tricky and you need to do some testing/perf check to get more info